# Python Collect URLS behind Links

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x

I have a few websites, each one of which has links on them. Behind those links, there are URLs that I can see in the status bar when I hover over the links. I need to get those links using Python. When I look at the page source, 'href' doesn't show those links, which gives me an indication that they are shown using Javascript.

Is there a way I could actually collect those URLs using Python? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a URL where we can see the behavior in action?

Comment: Sure - here it is: https://financials.psx.com.pk/ 

One thing: you will have to select some company from the dropdown on the left and then you can see the links under Reports column. Ideally, I'd like to download the financial reports for all the companies. So please do let me know if there's a way to do it in one shot for all the companies. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ahsan, did you find my answer helpful? Do you need any more help?

Comment: Yes, your answer definitely did. It helped me in making progress. Although I have raised another query to actually complete the task. It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643016/download-pdf-files-selenium-python?noredirect=1#comment110782171_62643016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your browser's developer tools, you can inspect the button elements and see that they are bound to `onClick` execute the function `getCompYData`. This function is defined as:

```
function getCompYData(t, a, b) {
  $("#yearlySmbData").empty(), $("#mheader").html(b), $.post("annQtrStmts.php", {
    name: "get_comp_y_data",
    smbCode: t,
    year: a
  }, function(t) {
    obj = JSON.parse(t), $("#yearlySmbData").createTable(obj, {})
  })
}
```

By executing an HTTP POST request to `annQtrStmts.php` with the `name` string, `smbCode` (e.g. AABS) and year (e.g. 2020) you should be able to access the appropriate file.

Bear in mind that doing this may be against this website's terms and conditions.

EDIT: Based on the updated question, you'd actually want to look in this function:

```
function getCompData() {
  var t = $("#country").val();
  $(".nav-link").removeClass("active"), $("#yearlyData").empty(), $("#annRpt").html("Financial Reports <br><br>" + $("#country option:selected").text() + " ( " + t + " )"), $.post("annQtrStmts.php", {
    name: "get_comp_data",
    smbCode: t
  }, function(t) {
    obj = JSON.parse(t), $("#yearlyData").createTable(obj, {})
  })
}
```

The endpoint is the same, but in this case you're passing a different string and no year.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getMyUrl(*arg):
#     print(arg)
    for _ in arg:
        if requests.head(_).status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(_).text, "html.parser")
            for a_tag in soup.findAll("a"):
                print(a_tag.attrs.get("href"))

#Use this like

if __name__ == "__main__":
    getMyUrl("https://www.google.com", "https://example.com")
```