# Download PDF files Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium

I need some help. I need to download financial statements that are located in PDF files to my MAC using Python. I've tried this using Selenium but unfortunately haven't been able to make progress.

Following is the URL: [financials.psx.com.pk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Q12.png)

When I load this URL, the page looks like so:
[image]

you see the dropdown on the left above "Company Name...", I need to select a company name there. Once I do that, then I see a window like this:
[image]

Every link under reports, when clicked downloads a PDF. I require those PDFs. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

I have tried the following code; it selects the company name and shows me the next page for a second but somehow another refresh happens, which leads me back to the original page:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="driver-path")
driver.get("https://financials.psx.com.pk/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("country")
drp = Select(elem)
drp.select_by_value("SHEL")
```

Actually, when I select using select_by_value, I can see the second window. I think the code is not stable. But, I am able to select a symbol from the dropdown and see the second page. Now, I need href's from the second page behind links such as 'Quarterly', 'Annual' etc.

Comment: First you need to navigate to the page and select the company name. Can you post the code you have tried to accomplish this task?

Comment: Yes, sure. I am editing the question with the code. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to type in that select field?

Comment: actually, when I select using `select_by_value`, I can see the second window. I think the code is not stable. But, I am able to select a symbol from the dropdown and see the second page. Now, I need href's from the second page behind links such as 'Quarterly', 'Annual' etc.